# Terraform SQL create users from variable

Tags: sql, user-accounts, terraform

I was told this might be a better spot for my question:

I have users defined in tfvars:

```
test_database_users = ["td" , "tdus", "tdbusrs"]
```

Resource is defined as:

```
resource "template_dir" "test_db_users" {
  ...
    vars {
         db_tusers = ${element(var.test_database_users, count.index)}"
         }
}
```

Trying to create a SQL command to create each database user which does not work:

```
CREATE USER ${element(db_tusers, 0)} FOR LOGON ${element(db_tusers, 0)};
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_datareader','${element(db_tusers, 0)}'
GO
```

I'm struggling with the proper syntax to bring each user into the create user command. Or am I going about it all wrong? I need to be able to create 3 db users from a script.